# Javascript - 'Function' is not a function singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, function, singleton

I've been trying to learn Javascript. This is my code - I'm trying to implement a singleton - but for some reason, I get the error setMessage is not a function in the line `firstInstance.setMessage("Message");`. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong - any help would be greatly appreciated.
`

```
var mySingleton = (function () {

   var instance;
   var message;

   function getInstance() {
            if (!instance) instance = new Object();
            return instance;
    }

    function setM (newMessage) {
            message = newMessage;
            return;
        }
        
    function getM() {
            return message;
        }

    return {
        createInstance:getInstance,
        setMessage:setM,
        getMessage:getM
       
    }

})();

var firstInstance = mySingleton.createInstance();
var secondInstance = mySingleton.createInstance();

//set messages

firstInstance.setMessage("Message");

console.log(firstInstance.getMessage());
console.log(secondInstance.getMessage());

//change messages 
secondInstance.setMessage("New");

console.log(firstInstance.getMessage());
console.log(secondInstance.getMessage());`
```

Comment: You are getting the error because you are creating an object without any properties: `instance = new Object();`.

Comment: Also, while you of course can try to apply concepts from other programming languages to JavaScript, this isn't really common. You can just instantiate an object directly. Even if you wanted to encapsulate `message`, why would you need to call `mySingleton.createInstance()` if you could as well just have `mySingleton` *be* the singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setMessage` and `getMessage` need to be on the `instance` you create, not in the object returned with the `createInstance`:

```js
var mySingleton = (function() {
  let instance;
  let message;

  function createInstance() {
    if (!instance) instance = { setMessage, getMessage };
    return instance;
  }
  function setMessage(newMessage) {
    message = newMessage;
  }
  function getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  return { createInstance }
})();

var firstInstance = mySingleton.createInstance();
var secondInstance = mySingleton.createInstance();

firstInstance.setMessage("Message");

console.log(firstInstance.getMessage());
console.log(secondInstance.getMessage());

secondInstance.setMessage("New");

console.log(firstInstance.getMessage());
console.log(secondInstance.getMessage())
```